# See what apps and data are taking up space in iOS, without iTunes?

Tags: ios

Is there a way i can see what apps and data are taking up space on my iPhone 8, running 12.4.1.

I know if i plug my phone into iTunes i can get a report on this, but wondered if its possible without iTunes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see what’s taking up all your storage space, open the `Settings` app, tap `General`, then tap `[Device] Storage`.

There, you’ll get an overview of how much storage space you have used and how much you have available, and you’ll get a list of how much space each app uses for the app and associated data.

[image]